# Processing 10 million datasets - php and sql

Tags: php, performance, parallel-processing, cron, bigdata

We're using PHP 7 and have a MySQL DB running on a Webserver with only 128 MB RAM.
We have a problem with processing tons of datasets. 
Simple description: We have 40.000 products and we want to collect data to these products to find out, if they need to be updated or not. The query which is collecting the specific data from another table with 10 Million datasets takes 1.2 seconds, because we have some SUM functions in it. We need to do the query for every product individually, because the time range which is relevant for the SUM, differs. Because of the mass of queries the function which should iterate over all the products returns a time out (after 5 min) - that's why we decided to implement a cronjob, which calls the function and the function continues with the product it ended the last time. We call the cronjob every 5 min.
But still, with our 40.000 products, it takes us ~30 hours until all the products were processed. Per cronjob, our function processes about 100 products...
How is it possible to deal with such a mass of data - is there a way to parallelize it with e.g. pthreads or does somebody have another idea? Could a server update be a solution?

Thanks a lot!
Nadine

Comment: "Could a server update be a solution?" Obviously, if you are running out of RAM (and probably CPU), yes. pthreads would use even more RAM and CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parallel processing will require resources as well, so on 128 MB it will not help.

Monitor your system to see where the bottleneck is.  Most probably the memory since it is so low.  Once you find the bottleneck resource, you will have to increase it.  No amount of tuning and tinkering will solve an overloaded server issue.

If you can see that it is not a server resources issue (!), it could be at the query level (to many joints, need some indexes, ...).  And your 5 min. timeout could be increased.

But start with the server.